# When do I have to hold during an instrument procedure?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, approach, instrument-procedures

Trying to stay fresh on instrument regs, and I'm reviewing when you are able to bypass a procedure turn. I'm reading that if you perform a teardrop entry for a hold, you may. Does that mean you have to do the entire hold before proceeding the approach when you do a parallel entry? 
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the reference for where you read that?

Comment: It was from an online document my cfi showed me.

Comment: In that case, yes, the "teardrop" in your question and my answer is not the same one that you do when entering a hold. You might want to edit the title of your question to reflect that.

Comment: The rule of thumb is overfly the holding fix twice.  The first time cross it fly the proper entry and the second time you pass it you are on course and continue with the procedure.

Comment: That is a good rule of thumb, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are thinking of [AIM 5-4-8 (b)(2)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM.pdf) [page 5-4-31], which states:

> 2. When a teardrop procedure turn is depicted and a course reversal is required, this type turn must be executed.

If so, have a look at the [Instrument Flying Handbook, page 7-31](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/FAA-H-8083-15B.pdf).  **The teardrop procedure turn is not referring to the same thing as a teardrop entry into a hold-in-lieu-of-procedure turn, it's something different entirely.**

[image]